# Activity Indicator does not show

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

Got a Problem that my activity indicator does not show up anyone a idea?

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *active;
    UIAlertView *alert_start;   
}
```

### ViewController.m

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home-de" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) webview 
{  
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [active startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webview 
{ 
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [active stopAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)tele_button:(id)sender
{
    //Local HTML Call Button
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"phone" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]];
    [self->webview loadRequest:theRequest];
}

- (IBAction)mail_button:(id)sender
{
    //Mail App Mail Button
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://info@optibelt.com"]];
}

- (IBAction)web_button:(id)sender
{
    //Local HTML Button
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://optibelt.com"]];
    [self->webview loadRequest:theRequest];
}

- (IBAction)news_button:(id)sender
{
    //local Home Button
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home-de" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]];
    [self->webview loadRequest:theRequest];
}
```

The activity indicator is set as behavior animating (checked) and hides when stopped (checked)

Would be great if i get some help :)

Comment: Throw in some `NSLog` calls to make sure you have connected the **IBActions** correctly.

Comment: how does i do it :) sorry first app :)

Comment: place `NSLog(@"it's connected!");` in each of the IBAction methods. If you see **it's connected!** in your console output, then they are correctly connected, if you do not see this, then you have done something wrong.

Comment: Well the actions work great but as far i put a NSLog into one of the voids it does not show up...

Comment: If you are connecting IBActions to UIButtons in Interface Builder, then they should work properly, you are obviously not calling the **void** methods or you would see the output.

Comment: Well the actions works great .... as before just the activity indicator does not show up...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check a couple of things.  First, check to see if the activity indicator outlet is connected in IB.  Second, check to see if the activity indicator is above the UIWebview.  It could be that it is being covered up.  You also might want to check that it isn't hidden in IB.

Good luck

Comment: well think it correct :/. if i set it to visible (not hide it with behaviors) it shows correct also it connected to active

Comment: well at last if i put a NSLog into the Voids they also does not show up ... so i think there is a other problem